# Resize borderContainer onClick titlePane

Tags: events, resize, dojo, border-container

I would like to resize a dijit borderContainer on the onClick event of a titlePane but the resize function behavior is very strange (Resize() works only after the second click). This is the code I use :

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" id="borderContainer">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" region="top" id="titlePane" title="Title">
    <script type="dojo/method">
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId("titlePane"), "onClick", function(){dijit.byId("borderContainer").resize()});
    </script>
</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="center" id="tabContainer">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="contentPane" title="content" selected="true">
        This is the content
    </div>  
</div>
```

Have you already seen this behavior? Your expertise would be very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `resize()` works also the first time, but you cannot see anything happening because you should call `resize()` not immediately after `onClick` occurs, but after the `titlePane's` resize animation finishes (200 ms later by default), because otherwise `borderContainer` resizes to the same size.

This is what I suggest:

```
dijit.byId("titlePane").watch("open", function(param, oldValue, newValue) {
    var animation = newValue ? this._wipeIn : this._wipeOut;
    var handler = dojo.connect(animation, "onEnd", this, function() {
        dijit.byId("borderContainer").resize();    
        dojo.disconnect(handler);            
    });
});
```

See a working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/E5CwV/

**EDIT:** On second thought, you can also create permanent connections on those two animations, but in my opinion it will lead to less readable code:

```
var titlePane = dijit.byId("titlePane");
var borderContainer = dijit.byId("borderContainer");
dojo.connect(titlePane._wipeIn, "onEnd", borderContainer, "resize");
dojo.connect(titlePane._wipeOut, "onEnd", borderContainer, "resize");
```

Comment: Thanks very for your prompt response. I completely forgotten the time for animation... Your example works perfectly. Hope that can help many poeple. Thanks phusick!